# Subtree finitely branching at limit nodes

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I was reading Chapter 3 - Coherent Sequences - in Handbook of Set Theory
and it says that every subtree of $\sigma \Bbb{Q}$ which is finitely branching at limit nodes is easily seen to be a special tree (bottom, [page 220](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=DLCyehuI0i0C&pg=PA220)). Why is that so obvious?

Here $\Bbb Q$ is $\omega^{<\omega}$ ordered by the right lexicographical ordering $<_r$: $s<_rt$ if $s$ is an end-extension of $t$, or if $s(i)<t(i)$ for $i=\min\{j:s(j)\ne t(j)\}$. $\sigma\Bbb Q$ is the tree of all well-ordered subsets of $\Bbb Q$, ordered by end-extension. A PDF of this chapter of the Handbook is available [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~stevo/cseq.pdf) in case the Google Books link doesn’t work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one construction: I agree it's not so obvious and the natural first attempt does not seem to work (and apologies for answering 8 years later, but putting it here for anyone in the future with the same question).

Call the tree $T$; it suffices to show that $T$ is a countable union of antichains. We will define $F\colon T\to(\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{Q})\cup\{\infty\}$ such that the preimage of each point is an antichain. Given $t\in T$, if $\operatorname{ht}(t)$ is a successor, set $F(t)=(0,\max(t))$. If $\operatorname{ht}(t)$ is a limit and $t$ has no successors in $T$, let $F(t)=\infty$. Otherwise, let $t^*$ be an immediate successor of $t$ with $\max(t^*)$ minimal; this is possible since $T$ is finitely branching at limit levels. Then set $F(t)=(1,\max(t^*))$. Now, suppose $s$ is a proper initial segment of $t$. There are two interesting cases: if $\operatorname{ht}(s)$ and $\operatorname{ht}(t)$ are both successors then $F(s)\neq F(t)$ since $\max(s)<\max(t)$. If both $\operatorname{ht}(s)$ and $\operatorname{ht}(t)$ are limits, then $s\cup\{\min(t\setminus s)\}\in T$ since $T$ is a tree, so $\max(s^*)<\sup(t)$ and $F(s)\neq F(t)$.